# 2d pathfinding around walls

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, graph-theory

In a recently released [game](http://planetbase.madrugaworks.com/), characters navigate (poorly) around a 2d martian surface performing tasks. I am trying to come up with a better algorithm (just for fun). You could use an algorithm like A* search, if you could construct the "edges" efficiently.

The problem: Given a set of non-intersecting lines and two points, start and finish, find the shortest route which does not intersect any of the lines.

[image: simple maze] [image: simple maze 2] [image: simple maze 3]

Comment: Hint: construct a graph with same vertices+S+F, where node is connected to all visible nodes from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is called "Any angle path planning". The short answer is there are ways of generating a visibility graph in O(n^2 log n) time (and maybe better), but since visibility graphs may have up to n^2 edges, algorithms using generating a VG will always have worst case performance slower than n^2.

VG algorithm: [Ch 13](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783540779735-c1.pdf) of *Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications* by de Berg

Most modern techniques avoid generating VGs and instead sacrifice correctness for asymptotically faster results. Some resources for the motivated:

- Lazy Theta*, an A* variant: [walkthrough](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/lazy-theta-star) | [paper](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aaai10b.pdf)
- [Sampling-Based Motion Planning](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch5.pdf), Ch 5 of *Motion Planning* by LaValle
- [CS course with lecture notes.](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/courses/planning-f07/)